# Is there a linux command to determine the window IDs associated with a given process ID?

Tags: linux, x11

Given a process iD of XX, I'd like to have a list of any window id's where _NET_WM_PID = XX.  Even better would be the oldest still active window id if possible.

I'm very new to linux, but what I'm trying to do is create a script that would take a command line, and see if there's a windows already open belonging to a process invoked with that same command line.  If so, just set focus to that window, otherwise execute the command line to get a new process going.  My intention is to use this in my ubuntu desktop, where I'll hook this script into my easystroke mouse gesture commands, so that, for example, every time I gesture for gmail I don't get a brand new gmail session, I just get brought to my existing gmail chrome app window.  Perhaps there's a much easier way to go about all this, but I haven't found my way to it yet.

With help, I've figured out how find a PID for a command line with pgrep and how to set focus to a window handle with wmctrl, but I'm stuck on getting from PID to window ID.

Comment: Seems like rather than trying mess with pgrep to find window id and pid, this will be much easier if you create a run file in a known location instead. Simply put, at the start of your script, create a file in `/run/user/$UID/myscript.lock` and dump the pid and window id there. Next time the script file runs, it checks that the window id in the valid is still valid and uses that. Or further, make that file a named socket, so you can interrogate the running script directly if it's a long running process.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

xwininfo and xprop permits to retrieve what you want, but it is a little tricky.

xwininfo permits to retrieve all known windows, and xprop to query X about a single window ID for your _NET_WM_PID parameter.

So far, a hacky way to do it would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

findpid=$1

known_windows=$(xwininfo -root -children|sed -e 's/^ *//'|grep -E "^0x"|awk '{ print $1 }')

for id in ${known_windows}
do
    xp=$(xprop -id $id _NET_WM_PID)
    if test $? -eq 0; then
        pid=$(xprop -id $id _NET_WM_PID|cut -d'=' -f2|tr -d ' ')

        if test "x${pid}" = x${findpid}
        then
            echo "Windows Id: $id"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
mycroft:~ $ ./find_windows.sh 1919
Windows Id: 0x1800748
Windows Id: 0x181b221
Windows Id: 0x1803ad5
Windows Id: 0x181f681
Windows Id: 0x181f658
Windows Id: 0x180006d
Windows Id: 0x1800003
Windows Id: 0x1800001
Windows Id: 0x180001e
```

As you will see, a single process may have a certain number of known windows, even if you see only one on your screen.

Maybe you should get these tools sources in order to make what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I started hacking around with this code when you originally posted it, but I got boggled and then sidetracked (hence the regrettably delayed acceptance)...still, this seemed to be giving me just wanted I wished for.

Comment: A one liner that would do it (stealing from Patrick) when you could easily select which window you're interested in is `xwininfo |sed -e 's/^ *//' | grep -E "Window id" | awk '{ print $4 }'`. Running xwininfo with no arguments or switches allows you to select with your mouse the window you want to know about. NOTE: I had to change the grep command a little for RHEL6.

Answer (score 43):

you can look up PIDs with **wmctrl** too, as a matter of fact, and I think that's a better way to do it. **xwininfo** will  return all sorts of entities which appear to be windows, but you won't really find them on your desktop.

If you do **man wmctrl**
, you'll find that **wmctrl -l** lists all windows that are actually visible on your desktop with (most importantly)  their *window ids* and *titles*. **-p** adds *PIDs* and **-x** will add *window classes*.

As the manual says ( RTFM, right? :D), wmctrl can also search through some of these and activate a window that matches the search. However, I have no idea what determines which one of all possible matches will be returned. On the other hand, you can use the provided listing function to write a wrapper that does the searching better and possibly based on some other properties (such as the timestamp of the last access to the window) which you can get by querying the provided *win id* to xprop, for example.

These lines of code below return the most recent instance a mate-terminal class window:

```
XTIME="_NET_WM_USER_TIME" #a shorter name for xprop query that shoul return timestamps
export TMPDIR=/dev/shm    #save tmp files to memory to make it faster
LST=`mktemp`              #tmp file to store our listing 
wmctrl -lx |  awk -F' ' '{printf("%s\t%s    \t",$1,$3); for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s",$i); printf("\n")  }'  > $LST #pretty-print our listing of windows into the tmp file
 #To each line of listing, prepend a timestamp acquired via an xprop call
 #Use awk to find a line whose 3rd column (winclass) matches the window class "mate-terminal.Mate-terminal" and among those that do, find the one whose timestamp is the largest
while read LINE; do ID=`echo "$LINE"|cut -f 1`; TIME=`xprop -id $ID $XTIME`;  TIME="${TIME/* = /}"; echo -e "$TIME\t$LINE" ; done <$LST ) | awk -v s="mate-terminal.Mate-terminal" '$3 == s {if($1>max){max=$1;line=$0};};END{print line}'
rm $LST  #delete tmp file
```

Anyhow, for the thing you describe you are building—if I were you, I would find out what class of windows your desired command generates and then base my search on that, rather than on PIDs. Alternatively, you could presume that command CMD will possibly generate windows with a class name that includes CMD.

After you have found your line, you should use the *window id*
to activate the window via wmctrl.

Hope this helps.

A side note: I've found that xdotool can do searches based on class names and window titles too, but it is *extremely slow*. On my computer, this bash script (that calls quite a couple of external utilites) is 10 times as fast as the compiled alternative that is xdotool :P.

Comment: But a benefit of xdotool is that it doesn't need an 'advanced' window manager, so it's definitely worth mentioning.

Comment: what does `TIME="${TIME/* = /}"` do?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Bash pattern substitution, see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#EXPREPL1

Comment: You can replace the "known_windows=" line in your script above with `known_windows=$(wmctrl -l | sed -e 's/^\([0-9a-fx]*\).*$/\1/' | xargs)`

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname
```

(As is: you don't need to replace those nice-sounding names with anything.)

Answer (score 7):

*[Here](https://github.com/computefoundation/gnu-linux-shell-scripting/tree/master/scripts/x11_management-output_only#x11-management---output-only) are multiple great X11 window management solutions.*

Try wmctrl. Here's a script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# 
# File:
#   getwindidbypid
# 
# Description:
#   Get the ID of a window by PID (if the process has a window).
# 
# Usage:
#   getwindidbypid <PID>
# 

while IFS= read line; do
  if [[ "${line}" =~ (0x)([0-9a-z]+)([ ][- ][0-9]+[ ])([0-9]*) ]]; then
    winId="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    pid="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    if [[ "${pid}" -eq "${1}" ]]; then
      WIND_IDS+=("${winId}")
    fi
  fi
done < <(wmctrl -lp)

if [ "${#WIND_IDS[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "${WIND_IDS[@]}"
fi
```

Example:

```sh
user ~ $  getwindidbypid 37248
0x05a00012
```

Answer (score 7):

## [xterm](/questions/tagged/xterm) `$WINDOWID` feature

Under `xterm` *environment* as some other implementation, you could find this variable:

```bash
echo $WINDOWID
58720292
```

So for any *other* pid:

Shortly by using `sed`:

```bash
targetpid=12345
sed -zne 's/WINDOWID=//p' /proc/$targetpid/environ
```

...

```
xdotool windowactivate $(sed -zne 's/WINDOWID=//p' /proc/$targetpid/environ)
```

Or in a *pure bash* function:

```bash
getWinFromPid () { 
    local pid=$1 array line
    [ -z "$pid" ] || [ ! -d /proc/$pid ] && return -1
    local -n result=${2:-winIDfromPid[$pid]}
    mapfile -d $'\0' -t array </proc/$pid/environ
    for line in "${array[@]}" ;do
        [ -z "${line%WINDOWID=*}" ] &&
            result=${line#*=} && return
    done
}
```

Then

```bash
getWinFromPid 123456 myWinId
xdotool windowactivate $myWinId
```

## For other term, like `gnome-terminal`:

This is strong because we don't want pid of `terminal` process, but pid of `shell` using terminal. For sample:

```bash
wmctrl -lp
```

don't show wanted pids!

So we have to navigate in hierarchy of process

## 1. Get Window ID from process ID

### 1a. Current active terminal window

From active session himself:

```bash
SHWINID=$(xprop  -root | sed -ne 's/^_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.*[)].*window id # //p')
```

This work as you type this in any *active* terminal console.

Then now, with `xdotool`:

```bash
sleep 12; xdotool windowactivate $SHWINID
```

You can now switch to another window, will be back in 12 seconds.

### 1b. Window ID from any shell or subprocess ID

I wrote this little function:

```bash
getWinFromPid () { 
    local pid=$1 ttypid crtpid wid xprop ttycheck
    [ -z "$pid" ] || [ ! -d /proc/$pid ] && return -1
    local -n result=${2:-winIDfromPid[$pid]}
    read ttycheck < <(ps ho tty $pid)
    ttypid=$ttycheck
    while [ "$ttypid" = "$ttycheck" ]; do
        crtpid=$pid
        read pid ttypid < <(ps ho ppid,tty $pid)
    done
    result=
    while [ -z "$result" ] && read wid; do
        xprop=$(xprop -id $wid)
        [ "$xprop" ] && [ -z "${xprop//*_NET_WM_DESKTOP*}" ] &&
            [ -z "${xprop//*_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = $crtpid*}" ] && result=$wid
    done < <(xwininfo -root -children -all |
       sed -e '1,/children:$/d;s/^ *\(0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+\) .*/\1/p;d')
}
```

Then

```bash
getWinFromPid <process id> [<variable name>]
```

If no *variable name* submited, this will populate global array `$winIDfromPid` with pid id as index number:

```bash
getWinFromPid 1234 winId
echo $winId
0x0100012345

getWinFromPid 1234
echo ${winIDfromPid[1234]}
0x0100012345

declare -p winIDfromPid 
declare -a winIDfromPid=([1234]="0x0100012345")
```

Nota: this was tested with `xterm`, `mate-terminal`, `konsole` and `gnome-terminal`.

Nota2: If you already have `wmctrl` installed, you could replace two last lines of function:

```bash
    done < <(xwininfo -root -children -all |
       sed -e '1,/children:$/d;s/^ *\(0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+\) .*/\1/p;d')
```

by:

```bash
    done < <(wmctrl -l|sed -ne 's/^ *\(0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+\) .*/\1/p');}
```

function will become approx 2time faster.

## 2. Get process running PID from a window ID

```bash
winID=0x123456
ps --ppid $(xprop -id $winID _NET_WM_PID|sed s/.*=//) ho sid |
    xargs -I{} -n1 ps --sid {} fw
```

or without *ID*, you will have to click with mouse:

```
ps --ppid $(xprop _NET_WM_PID|sed s/.*=//) ho sid|xargs -I{} -n1 ps --sid {} fw
```

Into a function

```bash
psWin() {
    ps --ppid $(xprop ${1+-id} $1 _NET_WM_PID|sed s/.*=//) ho sid |
        xargs -I{} -n1 ps --sid {} fw
}
```

Then:

```bash
psWin $SHWINID
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
30529 pts/2   Ss     0:00 bash
19979 pts/2   S+     0:00  \_ bash
19982 pts/2   S+     0:00      \_ xargs -I{} -n1 ps --sid {} fw
19986 pts/2   R+     0:00          \_ ps --sid 30529 fw
```

## 3. List of shell windows, with process

Finally, there is a little function for showing a list of window with process.

```bash
shWinList () {
    local pids=() wids=() wtitl=() ttys=() pid ttypid wpid crtpid line title desk ttycheck
    for pid in $(ps axho pid,tty| sed -ne 's/ pts.*//p') ;do     # list pid / tty
        wpid=$pid ttypid=
        read ttycheck < <(ps ho tty $pid)
        ttypid=$ttycheck
        while [ "$ttypid" = "$ttycheck" ]; do
            crtpid=$wpid
            read wpid ttypid < <(ps ho ppid,tty $wpid)
        done
        [ -e /proc/$pid ] && pids[crtpid]+=$pid\  ttys[crtpid]=$ttycheck
    done
    while read wid; do   title= pid= desk=                       # list wid / tty
        while read line; do
            [ "$line" ] && { 
                [ -z "${line%%_NET_WM_PID*}" ] && pid=${line##*= }
                [ -z "${line%%WM_NAME*}" ] &&
                    title=${line#*\"} title=${title%\"*}
                [ -z "${line%%_NET_WM_DESKTOP(*}" ] && desk=${line##*= } ;}
        done < <(xprop -id $wid)
        [ "${pids[pid]}" ] && [ "$title" ] && [ "$desk" ] &&
            wtitl[16#${wid#0x}]=${title} wids[16#${wid#0x}]=${pids[pid]} \
                 ttys[16#${wid#0x}]=${ttys[pid]}
    done < <(xwininfo -root -children -all |
                 sed -ne 's/^ *\(0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+\) .*/\1/p')
    for xwin in ${!wids[@]} ;do  out=                            # merge & print
        printf "  0x%x %-9s %-40s " $xwin "${ttys[$xwin]}" "${wtitl[$xwin]}"
        for pid in ${wids[$xwin]} ;do
            mapfile -d '' cmdl < /proc/$pid/cmdline
            echo -n " $pid[${cmdl[*]}]"
        done ; echo
    done
}
```

Then

```bash
shWinList
```

```
  0xa600024 pts/42    user@hostloc: /tmp            14817[bash]
  0x1c00024 pts/3     user@hostloc: ~               29349[watch ps --tty pts/3 fw] 31989[bash]
  0x4600024 pts/16    user@remote: ~                14441[ssh user@remote]
  0x6000024 pts/43    user@hostloc: ~               5728[bash]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have very similar used case like what in question. For me finding recursively with pattern matching by PID from list of all windows, is not a solution, because it will be very slow. If I have a single PID why scanning all windows? well, like other said, it is not simple because I have to make sure that this PID is belong to the parent process.

Using pgrep, I can narrow search result of PID first, by searching the combination of the command and its params using regex pattern:

```bash
    pgrep -f "{command}.*{command params}"
```

The trick is when running the command that I want to find later, I need to supply some kind of very specific identification pattern. For example, running an xterm instance with specific classname:

```bash
    xterm -name myterminal
```

Then, I can easily get all procesess of the corresponding instance with this command:

```bash
    pgrep -f "xterm.*-name myterminal"
```

Off course, that pgrep command might return multiple results, luckily  pgrep return the results in ascending order, so I am very sure the first one is the parent process who has the window:

```bash
    pgrep -f "xterm.*-name myterminal" | head -n1
```

Now I have single PID that I'm looking for, so I don't need to scan all windows and matching against this pid.
Back to basic, If the environment scope is  X11 then searching WindowID by PID using `xdotool` is enough for this case.

```bash
    WID="0x$(pgrep -f "xterm.*-name myterminal" | head -n1 | xargs xdotool search --pid | xargs printf "%x\n" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')"
    echo $WID
```

It will run very fast.

Notice that the output of xdotool is in Decimal format, while most of X-Window utilities command accept WindowID argument in hexadecimal format, something like `0x0XXXXXXX`, thus  just need to convert it with simple printf command.
In most use cases, transform all non-numeric digit to uppercase is needed to make sure compatibility with various tools e.g: `xdo`, `xprop`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using pids requires random window-manager restarts to resume functionality. Using process names proved itself to be much more useful, simplistic, and very reliable.

I use openbox and a keyboard. I created and posted a small bash program called [focus](https://github.com/paulihano/focus) to launch and rotate among existing windows based upon process names which fully demonstrates how to successfully associate processes with windows.

This is most likely the best answer because it is a 'goto that program' via the command line in one-liner easily declarable in a window manager keyboard configuration file. But, this answer is very low on the list of answers.