# How can I get the WID via bash which window the mouse pointer is over?

Tags: linux, bash, x11, mouseover, cinnamon

The question refers to:
Linux Ubuntu, with Cinnamon desktop

Several program windows can be displayed on a desktop.

How can I get the WID via bash which window the mouse pointer is over?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a linux command to determine the window IDs associated with a given process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250757/is-there-a-linux-command-to-determine-the-window-ids-associated-with-a-given-pro)

Comment: @tdy, My question is not releated to this.

Comment: What information do you want about the window, and what will you do with it?

Comment: @tgdavies, The WID of the window will be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community, Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test this at the moment, but maybe `xdotool` offers a way to get the window under the mouse cursor. From `man xdotool`:

> getmouselocation [--shell]
> Outputs the x, y, screen, **and window id of the mouse cursor**.

I assume the mentioned window id belongs to the window under the mouse cursor. To retrieve it, use

```
declare "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell | grep WINDOW)"
echo "$WINDOW"
```

The window id can then be used in other tools like `xwininfo -id <wdid>` to get more information.