# Finding window ID from process ID in linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos, window, pid

Currently working on making a script/command that I can run to save the states of all open terminals(gnome-terminal). I work with a lot of them on a VM and the VM freezes or starts doing weird stuff all the time(can't change this, stuck with it due to work reasons). So I'm trying to save the state of them so I can then restart the VM and run another command to pick up where I left off. I want to keep terminal tabs grouped together the same way I left them so I'm trying to match PIDs with window IDs so I can make nested gnome-terminal commands to open everything up correctly. I've tried a bunch of the suggestions for when you google 'how to get window ID from process ID and none of them have worked.

So, I'm looking for help to find the window ID from a process ID or something I can throw in my .bashrc that would allow me to keep track of windows/tabs. If it's something in the .bashrc, keep in mind I open multiple windows with multiple tabs and how I open them or close them varies(ctrl+shift+t vs gnome-terminal cmd, ctrl+shift+q vs window close) so traping signals is weird.

Comment: What Unix shell command do you enter in a terminal to see it's "window ID" or any other "window ID"?

Comment: When I'm in the terminal itself, I can use xdotool getactivewindow. Or I can list all windows with wmctrl -lp

Answer (score 0):

If you have `wmctrl` installed, then

```
wmctrl -lp
```

will list all windows with their associated porcess IDs.

Comment: That lists parent PIDs, which in my case, or test cases, have been the same, even across multiple windows of terminals

Comment: Which terminal are you using ?

Comment: Have a look at my [`getWinFromPid` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63979355/1765658)

Comment: Using bash, gnome-terminal. I'm using Pop_OS so Ubuntu based. And getWinFromPid didn't work either. I echo'd the result and it was empty

Comment: @SamKent `getWinFromPid` will create a aray variable: `$winIDfromPid` you could dump by `declare -p winIDfromPid` or `echo ${winIDfromPid[wantedPid]}`

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub If I undersand well, your function assumes that env var WINDOWID exists, which is not the case for gnome-terminal.

Comment: @Philippe Yes, there is a special way for *`gnome-terminal`* (with some limitations) also posted in same answer.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub If you meant the `special way` in this section `1b. Window ID from any shell or subprocess ID`. It returns nothing when I give $$ of gnome-terminal shell to the function.

Comment: @Philippe Same comment than previously: the function don't print anything but populate an ARRAY variable. see [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77116204/finding-window-id-from-process-id-in-linux/77116722?noredirect=1#comment135963234_77116722)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I have `declare -a winIDfromPid=([4773]="")`

Comment: You may have to ensure both packages are installed: `x11-utils` and `wmctrl`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255313/discussion-between-f-hauri-give-up-github-and-philippe).